# Katalon "Convert method declaration to closuse" when using Stream

Tags: java, groovy, katalon-studio

I have a simple code to compare 2 .txt files line by line. This is the code I have:

```
package csvPackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MapCompare {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    compararCSV("C:\\output_expected.csv",
            "C:\\output_real.csv");

}

public static void compararCSV(String expectedCSV,String realCSV) {
    //variables
    boolean linexlineTest = true;
    boolean countlinesTest = true;
    Path expectedFile = Paths.get(expectedCSV);
    Path realFile = Paths.get(realCSV);
    List<String> expectedFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> realFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    System.out.println("Archivo probado: " + realCSV + "\n");

    //leer expectedFile
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines( expectedFile )) 
    {
        lines.forEach(line->{expectedFileList.add(line.toString());});
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //leer realFile
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines( realFile )) 
    {
        lines.forEach(line->{realFileList.add(line.toString());});
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //compara la cantidad de líneas entre ambos archivos
    if(expectedFileList.size()!=realFileList.size()) {
        countlinesTest = false;
        System.out.println("LA CANTIDAD DE LÍNEAS ES DIFERENTE\n");
    }
    //valida línea por línea
    for(int i=0;i<realFileList.size();i++) { //cicla hasta la última línea del archivo
        if(!expectedFileList.get(i).equals(realFileList.get(i))) { //encontró diferencias
            linexlineTest = false;
            System.out.println("=================================");
            System.out.println("Línea:" + i + "\n");
            System.out.println("Valor esperado:\n");
            System.out.println(expectedFileList.get(i)+"\n");
            System.out.println("Valor actual:\n");
            System.out.println(realFileList.get(i)+"\n");
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    if (linexlineTest == true && countlinesTest == true) {
        System.out.println("PRUEBA PASADA");

    }else {
        System.out.println("PRUEBA FALLADA");
    }

}


}
```

This code works perfectly in Eclipse, however, when I try to create a Keyword in Katalon to call this method, I receive an error in the following piece of code:

```
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines( expectedFile )) 
    {
        lines.forEach(line->{expectedFileList.add(line.toString());});
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The error is this one:
[image]

I don't know why I'm receiving this error. I thought Katalon was able to read Java language.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you write Java code and you try to run it as Groovy code, problems are to be expected.

Groovy since 3.X supports the Java λ syntax, but before that, you have to use Groovy closure syntax.  That means: shift the opening `{` over - e.g.

`line->{expectedFileList.add(line.toString())}` becomes `{ line -> expectedFileList.add(line.toString())}`.

Same goes for the try/open-syntax, you see the actual error.  So you would have to rewrite that to `try`/`finally` to close in the `finally` block and so on.